# How to render fields body to result like image

Tags: odoo

[image]

[image]

How to render fields body to result like image

Comment: The question is a bit difficult to understand. But have you tried `nolabel="1"` on the body field view definition?

Comment: And please add your XML code to the question. Pictures are very helpful, but it's difficult to reference to code without code in the question.